# How to transfer #define-constants to another C++-project?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, configuration-files

I have two C++-projects in Visual Studio 2010, and one of them has to check if a `#define`-constant has been set in the other project (this one is a DLL, the first one is an executable). According to the constant being set in the executable the DLL should be compiled in another way (with `#ifdef` and `#ifndef`).
How is this possible, or is there another way to control the way the DLL is compiled remotely?

Comment: Do you need to know at compile time or run time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way is to stuff the defines into a central (shared) header, with traditional names as `config.h`, *instead of using the VS specific project settings*.

If you want to pry them out of existing project files, vim/grep on the `.vcproj` would normally do a decent job.

Comment: Good idea, I am going to convert my projects like this. Thank you!